# Specifying alternate background image using ngStyle

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to specify an alternate background image for a DIV like so:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(1.jpg), url(2.jpg)'}"></div>
```

Neither of the images are displaying (it works if I don't specify an alternate image).

Is it possible to specify multiple background images using `ngStyle`?

Comment: Depending on what should one background-image be shown over the other? Or should they always both be shown?

Comment: If the first one cannot be found then the second one should be shown. It works as normal CSS but not using Angular's `ngStyle`.

Comment: this does work, please see this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvuaf2?file=src/app/app.component.html

The first url has an invalid resource, so the second image is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aca6yd)

Template file

```
  <div  [ngStyle]='styles'>
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
      </div>
```

Ts file

```
 export class AppComponent  {

  name = 'Angular';
  img1 = 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_flwr.gif';
  img2 = 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif'
  isSelected: boolean =  true;
  styles = {};


  setCurrentStyles() {
    this.styles = { 
        backgroundImage: this.isSelected ?
                        `url(${this.img1})`:`url(${this.img2})`
    };
  }

  toogleImage() {
    this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    this.setCurrentStyles();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Saurabh (and to all others that answered). This is a nice pattern and I have implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

template.html

```
<div class="image" [ngStyle]="{background: !isActive ? 'url(https://www.fonewalls.com/wp-content/uploads/Aqua-Solid-Color-Background-Wallpaper-for-Mobile-Phone.png)' : 'url(https://www.fonewalls.com/wp-content/uploads/Midnight-Blue-Solid-Color-Background-Wallpaper-for-Mobile-Phone.png)'}"></div>
```

cmponent.ts

```
  isActive: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep your HTML clean with moving all the logic into the component.ts.

In the end you would have something like this:

```
<div class="image" [ngStyle]="{
  'background-image': 'url(' + backgroundImageString + ')'
}"></div>
```

Then in your component:

```
private defineBackImage(someArg) {
  if (stuff) {
    this.backgroundImageString = url1;
  } else {
    this.backgroundImageString = url2;
  }
}
```

You can trigger this function on init of according to specific events, also you can extend this logic to display much more than 2 backgrounds